# Turn a facelet tag into composite component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

Some time ago, based on one of @BalusC answers (really don't know which one of them) I wrote a facelet tag that is a kind of a button generator, that generates a variable number of buttons disposed side-by-side, each one with some parameters passed through the attributes.

Now I want to turn the facelet tag into a composite component (because on the latter, I have the cc:interface tag, that provides information to others developers who wants to use the custom component).

In the rewriting process I must deal with the actions attributes of the dynamically generated buttons. In the **facelet tag approach** I don't have to declare them as methods, so I can pass their names as simple strings and process them inside the facelet tag also as simple strings and call the action methods. In the **composite component approach** it seems that I must pass the methods names as actual methods names (by using the method-signature attribute of cc:attribute). The problem is: as I don't know previously the number of buttons (it generates the buttons dinamically), I'm not able to declare the action methods in the cc:interface section.

A simplified version of my working facelet tag is:

```
<c:set var="idValues" value="#{fn:split(ids,',')}" />
<c:set var="actionValues" value="#{fn:split(actions,',')}" />
<c:set var="numberOfButtons" value="#{fn:length(idValues)}" />

<h:panelGrid id="#{id}" columns="#{numberOfButtons}">
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{numberOfButtons-1}" varStatus="i">
        <p:commandButton id="#{idValues[i.index]}"
                         action="#{bean[actionValues[i.index]]}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

and the facelet tag can be used like this:

```
<my:button id="idButton" 
           ids="btnSave,btnCancel"
           actions="onSave,onCancel"
           bean="#{myBean}" />
```

**[EDIT]**

As sugested by @BalusC in the answers, adding code like below in the taglib.xml file was enough for the Eclipse autocompletion to work fine:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>button</tag-name>
    <source>tags/bottons.xhtml</source>
    <attribute><name>id</name></attribute>
    <attribute><name>ids</name></attribute>
    <attribute><name>actions</name></attribute>
    <attribute><name>bean</name></attribute>
</tag>
```

Comment: *"because on the latter, I have the cc:interface tag, that provides information to others developers who wants to use the custom component"* Which information exactly do you want to provide which is apparently impossible with the taglib.xml file? Nonetheless, this is perhaps food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822000

Comment: Some IDEs show a list of existing attributes when the user hit some key combination like ctrl+space in Eclipse, or get some help about the attributes (which I can put in the shortDescription attribute of cc:attribute). Ok... I`ll look for some information about the taglib.xml file. I haven't given it any great importance... at least until now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thank you, @BalusC. The taglib.xml does what I need. I underestimated its cababilities.